# Give publish permission to Facebook Canvas app for testing

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have created a simple canvas app. I have set my access Token in the facebook but this access token is set with scope public_profile, basic_info, user_friends

I also want to add public_action so i can test posting too.

I am using php FacebookSdk 4.0 with following code

```
// init app with app id (APPID) and secret (SECRET)
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('{app_id}','{app_secret}');
$helper = new FacebookCanvasLoginHelper();

try {

          $session = $helper->getSession();

} catch (\Exception $ex) {
  echo $ex->getMessage();
}

if($session) 
{
    $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
    try{
         $response = $request->execute();
         $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
         //echo  print_r( $graphObject, 1 );
    } catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
         echo $ex->getMessage();
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }

    try{
     $response = (new FacebookRequest(
      $session, 'POST', '/me/feed', array(
        'link' => 'www.example.com',
        'message' => 'User provided message'
      )
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject();
    } catch(FacebookPermissionException $ex) {
         echo $ex->getMessage();
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
else 
{
 // show login url  
}
```

With error

```
(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

How can I give myself publish permissions?

I have managed to get publish permissions using following code

```
          $url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxx
&redirect_uri=https://xxxx/v1/&scope=publish_actions';
```

Following is my code from Fb developer docs

```
  try {

    $response = (new FacebookRequest(
      $session, 'POST', '/me/feed', array(
        'link' => 'www.example.com',
        'message' => 'User provided message'
      )
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject();

    echo "Posted with id: " . $response->getProperty('id');

  } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {

    echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
    echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();

  }
```

I am getting error

```
Exception occured, code: 100 with message: Invalid parameter
```

Comment: You shouldn't show your app secret in public!

Comment: @Tobi it was a test app but thanks for that....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apparantly add the list of requested permissions in the `getLoginUrl()`

```
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(["public_profile", "publish_actions", ...]);
```

See

- https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/master/src/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php#L85
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0#authentication

Be aware that with v2.0, you need to have your permissions reviewed before you can request them with your app: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

Comment: firstly, for canvas we are Using FacebookCanvasLoginHelper as per FB documentation. I am not sure what should I do now. also i am a devleoper i don't think i need for the app to be reviewed for public_actions right?

Comment: There's no permission "public_actions". You nee to gather the permission first before you can use it.

Comment: sorry its publish not public:)

Comment: I have managed to call a dialog within app and get the permissions however I get this error Whenever i try to post something Exception occured, code: 100 with message: Invalid parameter. I am editing my above code